# Real url self cache cleaning ways in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, realurl

Is there any way to clear Real url related tables cache cleaning that can be done for specified time period?

For example annually all real url related tables are got empty automatically via some config settings or ways like this which does not done manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build in mechanism to clear these tables automatically. Even for manually clearing you need extras. There is/was(?) an extension which adds a button to clear realurl cache, but no automatism.
If you know which SQL-queries you want executed it should be easy to add a simple cron-job.